# My program is running perfectely on localhost but it bring error when implemented on two machines

Tags: java, client-server

Am on a client and server project, which each client & server sends file to each other. The program aim is sending and receiving file at both end.
The program run very perfectly on local-host but it bring error when implemented on two machines haven specify the server machine IP, yet it still brings error. I just want to know what are the possible causes that hindered the program from running on Machines.

SERVER SIDE

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class ServerHandler {
    PrintStream printStream;

    public ServerHandler(){

    }
    public static void main(String [] args){
        new ServerHandler().sentIT("Super_woman.avi");
    }

    public void sentIT(String pathName) {

        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(65141);
            System.out.println("Server Started");
            Socket socket = server.accept();
            System.out.println(" "+socket.getLocalAddress());
            int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 50;
            byte[] buffer;
            buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            File paths = new File(pathName);
            BufferedInputStream input = 
                new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(paths));
            DataOutputStream ou = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            try (BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(ou)) {
                ou.writeUTF( paths.getName());
                int len, i=0;
                while ((len = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                input.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error sending File/n FAILED", "Sending Failed",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

CLIENT SIDE

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ClientReceive{
    private DataInputStream ins;
    private BufferedInputStream bis;
    private BufferedOutputStream out;

    public ClientReceive(){

    }
    public static void main(String [] args){
        new ClientReceive().receiveFile();
    }

    public void receiveFile() {

        try {
            int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 50;
            byte[] buffer;
            buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 65141);
            ins = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            String path=ins.readUTF();
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(ins);
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("HotSpotFileShare_"+path));
            int len;
            while ((len = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, len);   
            }  
            out.flush();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File "+path+" Received Successfully", 
                    "File Received", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            //System.out.println("\nDone!");    
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Operation Failed", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        finally {
            if (ins != null && out != null){

                try {
                    out.close();
                    ins.close();

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unable to Close Connection", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? How are you running it on a server? What JRE does your computer have? What JRE does the server have?

Comment: Your client wants to connect to "localhost". What do you expect to happen when your server is **not** running on "localhost"?!

Comment: i have already implement it using   IPv4  address of the Server machine.

Comment: @Ola_Code are you sure that it manages to read from the server?

Answer (score 2):

In the client, you have this:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 65141);
```

but you don't want to connect to localhost, so instead of `localhost`, put in the ip address of the computer running the server.

This would work If they are on the same network (LAN, namely). 
To get the server computer's IP (on windows) you can open CMD (Ctrl+R -> type `cmd.exe` and press enter) and type into CMD this:

```
ipconfig
```

the number sequence in the line saying `IPv4...` is your IP address

Comment: of course i have tried using the server machine IP but it doesn't work. the connection usually breaks while sending the file.

Comment: The method sending the file might be invoking `socket.close()`

Comment: In fact, it probably runs into an error when sending the file, and goes into the `finally` block.

Comment: but i have already showcase the source code, may be u should check and help me where the problem is

Comment: In a moment, checking things now.

Comment: @Ola_Code can you please write the output of `String path=ins.readUTF();` ?